# Emf & Internal Resistance - What causes the internal resistance

Tags: electricity

If I were to say;

"Chemical reactions produce electrical energy (Used to make the electrons move) – EMF (“Carried” by Electrons) collides with lattice ions inside the battery creating resistance (INTERNAL RESISTANCE) – Power transferred to surroundings (Energy wasted as heat)"

Does this make sense or is it correct ? It is slightly short hand as it is easier for me to understand.

**ALSO:** The *Terminal Potential Difference* is the measured value across the cells giving effectively the emf-Lost volts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Batteries have three parts, an anode (-), a cathode (+), and the electrolyte. The cathode and anode (the positive and negative sides at either end of a traditional battery) are hooked up to an electrical circuit.

The chemical reactions in the battery causes a build up of electrons at the anode. This results in an electrical difference between the anode and the cathode. You can think of this difference as an unstable build-up of the electrons. The electrons wants to rearrange themselves to get rid of this difference. But they do this in a certain way. Electrons repel each other and try to go to a place with fewer electrons.

In a battery, the only place to go is to the cathode. But, the electrolyte keeps the electrons from going straight from the anode to the cathode within the battery. When the circuit is closed (a wire connects the cathode and the anode) the electrons will be able to get to the cathode. In the picture above, the electrons go through the wire, lighting the light bulb along the way. This is one way of describing how electrical potential causes electrons to flow through the circuit.

However, these electrochemical processes change the chemicals in anode and cathode to make them stop supplying electrons. So there is a limited amount of power available in a battery.

When you recharge a battery, you change the direction of the flow of electrons using another power source, such as solar panels. The electrochemical processes happen in reverse, and the anode and cathode are restored to their original state and can again provide full power.

For your second question:

The **potential difference** across the battery , from - to + , is positive and equal with $E$ ( EMF) .